# Почему страница прошедших ивентов пустая?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, знаки, встречи-сообщества

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/badges/get/events?tab=past

При условии, что знак https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/196/not-a-robot есть у 16 пользователей.

Comment: например потому, что в английской версии там строка: [Upcoming Events](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/get/events) что совсем не прошедшие :)

Comment: @Grundy сравните вашу ссылку и ту, что приведена в вопросе. https://stackoverflow.com/badges/get/events?tab=past

Comment: О! не видел там вкладки :-) Но вполне логично, что для появления на этой вкладке, событие должно быть добавлено :-) так как у нас события не добавлялись их тут и нет :-)

Comment: @Grundy ну так события были? Были. Вопрос то в этом и состоит, почему они не был добавлены.

Comment: Мне кажется я знаю одного человека, который за это отвечает :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я верно понимаю идею позади, то эта страница про события, в которых Stack Overflow (компания) принимает участие как партнер, то есть, например, в случае конференции есть стенд компании, где можно найти сотрудников и поговорить с ними. В основном такие мероприятия организует отдел маркетинга.

На сегодняшний день, [встречи-сообщества](/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0) — события другого рода. Знак «не робот» принявшие участие получают, но встречи не отображаются в указанном списке.

Comment: Компания не заинтересована в поддержке ру конференций? Думаю, на том же хайлоде неплохо стенд SO смотрелся бы.

Comment: @Suvitruf, таки прояви инициативу

Comment: @Grundy я ж не сотрудник.